# How I can move content of multiple folders one level up?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have multiple folders containing my project video screenshots.

```
/vid1/screenshots/
/vid2/screenshots/
/vid3/screenshots/
/vid4/screenshots/
```

....so one 70 of them.

How I can move the content of all screenshots folder one level up and delete screenshots folder. I want all images to be in vid1,vid2... respective folder. Like move content up and zap in linux command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in /vid{1..4}/screenshots; do
    mv "$dir"/* "${dir%/*}"
    rmdir "$dir"
done
```